# What is the carbon content of tree seeds and would they be suitable to balance nitrogen rich compost?

Tags: trees, seeds, compost, nitrogen, carbon-nitrogen-ratio

On top of my garage was a full 2 inches of densely composted material that I presume has built up over many years. Right above the garage are 2 trees that seem to shed hundreds of thousands of tiny seeds. I need carbon matter to balance all the fruit and veg peelings that I create and am wandering what the carbon content of a tree seed might generally be and could I use it instead of sawdust and in what proportions would I add them.

I don't know yet what the tree is but I'm thinking a birch of some kind (small, green, classic leaf shape about 1" long). I'm presuming that the seeds are nutritional dense as it needs to provide the young seedling with a start in life much like the contents of an egg to a hatch-ling. Not knowing what these nutrients are I wander if they will further imbalance the nitrogen levels of my kitchen waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seed itself is probably not a great thing to add to compost in large quantities. Seeds have protective coatings on them that will take a very long time to break down.

However, everything around the seed that falls from the trees like the husks and pods anything else is likely a good material to use in compost.

**So, short answer: throw it all in.**

I judge quantity using a 1 handful to 2 handfuls ratio. This is generally a good rule of thumb for nitrogen (1 handful) to carbon (2 handfuls).

You mentioned seeds and sawdust as your sources of carbon and I just want to caution you that compost needs some diverse sources of carbon ideally. Wood chips, dried leaves, dried garden cuttings are all good carbon sources. Maybe search the internet for lists of carbon sources so you can get more good sources mixed in.